# Haskell: List comprehension unique char from string

Tags: haskell

Here is my current list comprehension: `[((a,b),a+1) | a <- [1,2], b <- "ab"]`

Current output: `[((1,'a'),2),((1,'b'),2),((2,'a'),3),((2,'b'),3)]`

Intended output: `[((1,'a'),2),((2,'b'),3)]`

How can I edit my list comprehension to achieve the intended output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two generators produces all possible combinations of the items. You want a *single* generator produced by zipping the two lists together.

```
[((a,b), a+1) | (a, b) <- zip [1,2] "ab"]
```

You can also write

```
[(t, a+1) | t@(a, _) <- zip [1,2] "ab"]
```

or

```
[(t, fst t + 1) | t <- zip [1,2] "ab"]
```

because you don't care about `b` except to reconstruct the tuple you just unpacked from `zip`.

GHC also provides an extension, [`ParallelListComp`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/parallel_list_comprehensions.html), to zip the generators implicitly.

```
> :set -XParallelListComp
> [((a,b), a+1) | a <- [1,2] | b <- "ab"]
```

Note the use of `|` instead of `,` to separate the two generators.

Comment: If the string is not fixed at a length of 2 characters, it may be beneficial to: `zip [1..] "ab"`